# What could be causing this "NULL could not be resolved" error?

Tags: c

In Eclipse I have this C program. It compiles fine in Eclipse in Windows, but when I try to compile it in Eclipse in OSX, I get several of these errors.

```
Symbol 'NULL' could not be resolved
```

The code that causes it is this:

```
pdPASS != xTaskCreate( uartUI, (signed char*)"Uart UI", STACK_BYTES(1024*6), &System, PRIORITY_LOW,  &System.task.userInterface )
```

Why is Eclipse showing this error for the same program in OSX but not in Windows?

Comment: Possibly duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433448/eclipse-cdt-symbol-null-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: You're missing a required `#include` for `<stddef.h>` (or one of several other headers that defines `NULL`); see the duplicated question.  Probably on Windows some header you `#include` in turn `#include`s something that defines `nULL`.  Oh, and according to the reference I just Googled, the second argument to `xTaskCreate()` is of type `const portCHAR * const`; why are you casting it to `signed char*`?

Comment: Don't blame the messenger.  Don't blame the IDE for this.  This is a portability bug in your C code, plain and simple.  (Removed IDE / eclipse tags)

Answer (score 2):

As noted above:

> You're missing a required #include for  (or one of several other headers that defines NULL); see the duplicated question. Probably on Windows some header you #include in turn #includes something that defines nULL. Oh, and according to the reference I just Googled, the second argument to xTaskCreate() is of type const portCHAR * const; why are you casting it to signed char*