# Fatal error: stdio.h No such file or directory

Tags: c, eclipse

So, I had eclipse working, but I had to send my computer in for a replacement. Set up Eclipse with MinGW like I did before, and now it cannot resolve any of the header files.

I've edited the environment variables and all that jazz, so I dunno what to do.

EDIT: Also getting an unresolved inclusion error.

Comment: Is the error message coming from Eclipse or from your compiler?

Comment: The error is coming from eclipse

Comment: @JakeCooper, could you please post the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Ill upload a screenshot in just a sec. My error has changed around a bit as i've tried a couple things.

Comment: So Eclipse complains -- what happens when you compile the file anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

or

```
#include "stdio.h"
```

?

The first one tells it to look in the standard library, while the second tells it to look locally. Try switching to the first.

Comment: Already using the first one, now im getting the "unresolved inclusion error" as well.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337757/unresolved-inclusion-stdio-h

Comment: `#include "stdio.h"` will search locally *and then* in standard locations.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem, was missing the libraries is MinGW, so I added the ones I needed and voila, its working.

Thank you for everyones suggestions!

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer. It won't gain you any points, but it does show that the question is closeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```