# Unresolved inclusion: <stdio.h> in Eclipse helios (Windows 7 64bit)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt, windows64

I am trying to install Eclipse on my computer: I have a 64bit Windows 7.

I have installed a 64bit Java, and a 64bit version of Eclipse helios (C/C++).

When I tried to compile a hello world project I got an error

> Unresolved inclusion: < stdio.h>

I have inserted another space since the text didn't render.

I have tried looking for solutions on this site and on Google, but the best thing I found was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337757/unresolved-inclusion-stdio-h).

But I don't know where to locate stdio.h myself.. I have used the search on my computer and didn't find such a file. maybe I don't have one, what should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

The location of your headers depends on what tool chain you are using. You can go to `Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor` to find out which it is. Once you know that, you need to locate the headers and include them (in manner [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337757/unresolved-inclusion-stdio-h) suggests). For example [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/285005/) is example of someone having the same issue with MinGW tool chain. Find you about your tool chain and I will attempt to guide you if I will be able to.

Comment: I have installed MinGW. Now it recognizes the library but doesn't compile the project with the error: Cannot run program "make" (in directory "[path is given]"): CreateProcess error=2, ???????? ??? ?????? ???? ?? ?÷??? ?????)

Answer (score 1):

If you changed the current toolchain, please reopen(close and open) the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. It is due to not installing cygwin/gcc and not adding cygwin_install_path/bin to Path.

Answer (score 0):

What is the suffix of your filename - foo.c? foo.cc?

By default, Eclipse assumes that .c files should be parsed to the C standard, while .cc files should be parsed as C++. So, if you have C++ code in a file ending with .c, it tries to parse C++ as C, and often stumbles as soon as it hits a standard library include.

The easiest solution is to rename your files to *.cc. You can see Eclipse's list of suffix associations by going to `Window->Preferences->C/C++->File Types`, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to change the defaults.