# Unresolved inclusion in nsight-Eclipse for C standard library headers

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, nsight, std

This is the exact same question as

[“Unresolved inclusion” error with Eclipse CDT for C standard library headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9337757/1593077)

Except that I'm using NVidia NSight Eclipse - the Eclipse bundled with CUDA. When I right-click a project and view it's properties, I don't see a C++ General or C/C++ Build line in the options tree. Can I enable them somehow? Do I need to install something as a plugin?

Comment: @vitrums: That is, indeed, another issue...