# View default include path of C headers in Mac OS X by `gcc -v`?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos

I tried to find the default include path of the C compiler in Mac OS X (Mavericks) by using `gcc -v`:

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

It seems to tell me the path is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`, but I'm afraid it is not the true path. I think the true path for including standard C library is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include` because `<sys/syscall.h>` locates in the later path, which is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/sys/syscall.h`

Does anyone have ideas about how to view all the default include path of C library in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to ask the *preprocessor*, not *gcc*, for telling the default include path.

You can say:

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` -v
```

In order to list default include path for both C and C++:

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
```

(The *path* that you've listed above is the one that was used to *configure* GCC while building.)

---

Another way to list the default include path would be:

```
gcc -x c -v -E /dev/null

gcc -x c++ -v -E /dev/null     # (for C/C++)
```

Comment: That doesn't work on OS X Mavericks (Xcode 5) since `gcc` actually invokes `cc` which is `clang`.  And they all return `cc1` which doesn't actually exist.

Comment: I tried your ways and found that only `gcc -x c++ -v -E /dev/null` works for Mac OS 10.12.5.