# OSX gcc not finding installed libs

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc, clang

I'm rediscovering the horror of compiling C. I just installed `libtins` from http://libtins.github.io, following the usual `./configure` -> `make` -> `sudo make install` pattern.

`sudo make install` definitely put headers in `/usr/local/include/tins` but it doesn't seem like `g++` is able to see them.

following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852199/view-default-include-path-of-c-headers-in-mac-os-x-by-gcc-v), I tried running `gcc -x c++ -v -E /dev/null` in order to see the include paths.

```
clang -cc1 version 5.1 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

I would have expected to see `/usr/local/include` in there somewhere. Are the default paths paths all inside the Xcode app now?

**app.cpp**

```
#include <tins/tins.h>

int main() {
    return 1;
}
```

**compile command**

`g++ app.cpp -ltins`

**result**

`app.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'tins/tins.h' file not found`

Any idea how to make `g++` see the headers?

Comment: I have since tried putting the `tins` folder into `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include`. g++ immediately picks it up. That shouldn't be necessary though, should it?

Comment: It is *not* necessary. `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` are *not* part of the default search paths for the preprocessor on OS X. The output you're showing is evidence of that. You can either (a) modify the default search path for the preprocessor (not recommended) or (b) modify the preprocessor search sources using `-Ipath` (and *likely* associated  `-Llibpath` for the linker). `clang` *used to do this for you* (gcc did not) for `/usr/local/include`. However, mine *does* [see here](http://pastebin.com/vbc1LJH6) in gcc-mode (interesting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't set the [include path](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) when compiling. Hence, the correct compilation line should be:

```
g++ app.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -ltins
```