# boost headers not found issue in mac os x

Tags: macos, boost, compiler-errors, include, homebrew

While including boost headers, I am getting not found error like the following-

```
 fatal error: boost/config.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/config.hpp>
```

I am using Mac OS X 10.9, and installed boost through brew. I can see all the boost headers at /usr/local/include/boost folder. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the make output log with might help others to get more idea on the error

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that /usr/local/include/boost/config.hpp exists, you need to add /usr/local/include to the compiler include search path; for gcc you can do this by adding -I /usr/local/include to the command line (or relevant part of the makefile).

What compiler are you using, and did you install it via homebrew?

Comment: I installed GCC 4.9 using homebrew. Is there any way to check the include directories associated with GCC? Since /usr/local/include is the default location for homebrew header files, I thought GCC would automatically get the header files from there.

Comment: I just found ways to check include path(s) from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852199/view-default-include-path-of-c-headers-in-mac-os-x-by-gcc-v ... And /usr/local/include is there.

Answer (score 2):

- make sure to use the right compiler - just gcc gets the wrapper around Apple's clang, /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 is what you installed with brew
- did you add an -I /usr/local/include to your compilation?
- as already written, a full dump of the error message would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Goto the following folder and find the installed boost library folder. I paste mine as an example folder path;

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1
```

You need to find the most recent boost folder. If not there, you should install the boost library via brew

```
brew install boost
```

I'm assuming that you are using Xcode for your project. After the preceding steps, you need to add correct boost folder paths to your Xcode project. Open your Xcode project goto **"Header Search Paths"** and add the **boost** folder's parent folder path. Check the screenshot that I attached (ss-1 [ss-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CtSu.png)).

e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/include/` for the **Header Search Paths** (ss-2 [ss-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG5rd.png))

Also, you need to add **Library Search Paths** in your Xcode project. 
e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib/` for the **Library Search Paths** (ss-3 [ss-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2msVK.png))

Answer (score 0):

Install the library:

```
brew install boost
```

Select your project name in the Project Navigator, then in the Build Settings tab under Search Paths, double-click to the right of Header Search Paths, then enter the full path to folder: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.84.0_1/include/