# Eclipse shows errors while build works fine

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have created two c++ hello world applications. First one - `C++ Managed Build`, second one - `Makefile Project`. First one builds fine and has no error detected, while second one builds and runs, but shows errors in IDE:

[image]

Why do I see those error? How to get out of them?

Comment: Did you try _reindexing_? Also common include paths setups could help for the makefile project.

Comment: Those are not errors, just warnings that Eclipse is unable to locate the inclusions. The "unresolved inclusion" issue is discussed, e.g.,  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9337757/) and [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/200049/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unresolved inclusion" error with Eclipse CDT for C standard library headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337757/unresolved-inclusion-error-with-eclipse-cdt-for-c-standard-library-headers)