# Eclipse CDT C++ NULL not resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

Related: [Eclipse CDT "Symbol NULL could not be resolved"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433448/eclipse-cdt-symbol-null-could-not-be-resolved)

I was under the impression that `NULL` was a standard macro in C++ and didn't need any headers to be included.  Eclipse, on the other hand, thinks it doesn't exist.

Is there some way to remind Eclipse that I'm in C++ mode not C mode for this file, and therefore to shut up about the NULL problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is NULL undeclared?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924664/why-is-null-undeclared)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I was under the impression that NULL was a standard macro in C++.

It is, but it's not part of the language.  You still need to include `<cstddef>` or `<cstdlib>`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

[Why is NULL undeclared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924664/why-is-null-undeclared)

Quoted from the top-answer on that question.

> NULL is not a built-in constant in the C or C++ languages. In fact, in C++ it's more or less obsolete, just use a plain literal 0 instead, the compiler will do the right thing depending on the context.
>
> Otherwise, add
>
> ```
> #include <stddef.h>
> ```
>
> to get the NULL definition.
>
> UPDATE: I had the wrong header, corrected now. Thanks!
> (Quoted from Unwind)