# Unresolved inclusion < stdio.h>

Tags: c, eclipse, codesourcery

I have installed Motorola FX7500 Embedded SDK(with Sourcery CodeBench) and opened a sample project using that SDK ( which is an Eclipse version). I imported a sample project and there is no error, but when I open a .c or .h file I get lots of errors, the errors are all like this :

- Symbol 'EOF' could not be resolved
- Symbol 'NULL' could not be resolved
- Type 'wchar_t' could not be resolved

Also it gives error all standard C libraries like this :

> Unresolved inclusion : < stdio.h>

How can I get rid of these kind of errors in Eclipse? Is there a problem with paths or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: This seems something related... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433448/eclipse-cdt-symbol-null-could-not-be-resolved

I hope it could help.

Comment: @0Andrea thank you but my problem seems different, the code doesn't see any of the library includes.

Comment: Yes, I also have < stdlib.h> , < string.h> and more and I get the errors at all of these lines

Comment: There is no space in the code.

Comment: Since this is for an embedded project, maybe this is a "freestanding" environment without most of the standard library. If this is the case you should see the macro `__STDC_HOSTED__` set to `0`.

Comment: The paths of the libraries were obsolete by default in Eclipse, I corrected them by hand and the errors disapeared. Thank you very much.